# Syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Tags: php

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

```
<?php echo Form::open(['to' => 'product-search', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'id' => 'form-product-search', 'class' => 'form-inline', 'style' => 'text-align:center']); ?>
```

I'm not sure why i'm receiving this error after i migrate to ubuntu server. it used to be working fine on WAMP.

I tried commenting the code out too, it gives the same error, Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might run on `PHP < 5.4`, so you need to define the array with the classic definition:

```
 <?php echo Form::open(array('to' => 'product-search', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'id' => 'form-product-search', 'class' => 'form-inline', 'style' => 'text-align:center')); ?>
```

(and do this on every array declaration with `[]`)... or upgrade to PHP 5.4+ :-)

Answer (score 4):

This error is occured due to your PHP Version.

```
['to' => 'product-search', 'autocomplete' => 'off', 'id' => 'form-product-search', 'class' => 'form-inline', 'style' => 'text-align:center']
```

You can't defined `array` like this in `PHP < 5.4 version`.

Comment: Okay Thanks, i will check the version out